# Prolog : how to detirmine if there are duplicate element in a list (not consecutive)

Tags: prolog

Im wondering how can i write a predicate /1 which determines if a given list has duplicates or is unique **without pre-defined/built-in predicates**?

myFunc([a,b,c,d]) = true

myFunc([**a**,b,**a**,d]) = false

What i have so far is :

```
myFunc([X|Y]) :- helpFunc(Y,X).
myFunc([]).
helpFunc([],_).
helpFunc([Y|X], Y) :- helpFunc(X,Y).
```

This returns true only if there are consecutive repeated element in the list.

ex.

myFunc([1,3,a,4,b]) = false -- > should return true

myFunc([1,**3**,a,**3**,b]) = false -- > should return false

--

myFunc([**3,3,3,3**]) = true

any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to do this is :

```
duplicate(List):-
 append(X,Y,List),
 member(M,X),
 member(M,Y).
```

A list has duplicate elements, if you can split it in to two lists and there is the same member of both these lists.

As prolog does not have functions, a declarative name would be better.

I have used the built in member/2 and append/3 but if you insist you can easily look up the definitions of these.

Comment: "without pre-defined/built-in predicates"

Comment: https://www.cpp.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/2_7.html and http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse24